# linux kernel waitqueues - printk not showing in message log

Tags: linux-kernel

I'm noticing some strange behavior in a kernel module. When I run the following code (with waitqueues). After finish_wait(), printk() doesn't show up in the kernel log.
Also line 5 only prints once. Any ideas what is going on?

```
DEFINE_WAIT(wait);
DECLARE_WAIT_QUEUE_HEAD(wait_q);
flags |= O_NONBLOCK;
while (( err = kthread->sock->ops->accept(kthread->sock, kthread->sock_send, flags) ) < 0){
    printk("%s: before prepare_to_wait err = -%d\n", __func__,err);
    prepare_to_wait(&wait_q, &wait, TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE);
    if(kthread_should_stop()){
        printk("%s: killing thread\n", __func__);
        msleep(1000);   
        finish_wait(&wait_q, &wait);
        goto close_and_out;
    }
    schedule();
}
finish_wait(&wait_q, &wait);
printk("after finish wait: This doesn't show up in kernel logs...\n");
```

Comment: If other `printk`s are working then, I suspect that the control never reached the last `printk`. There are many ways here that the control might not come to your desired `printk` - An infinite `while` loop, giving up control through `schedule`, `goto` statement.

Comment: This code is within an infinite while loop. Everything seems to be functioning fine,which is strange. This is a network server and everything seems to be working correctly which I can verify with a networking client. -- but printk() is not showing up.

Answer (score 2):

Add the Priority to the log message :

Like : printk(KERN_ALERT your message);
Also there will be no "comma" between KERN_ALERT and your message 
try with different LEVELS if not KERN_ALERT .

Rgds,
Softy

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It turns out that something else was going on. I decided to try another approach where I'm not using waitqueues. I even tried KERN_EMERGENCY and nothing was showing up..